# How can I know the position of a row after sorting it in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like following and I want to know only the exact position of a specific row after sorting it according to marks.

| StudentID | ExamID | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 80 |
| 2 | 100 | 85 |
| 3 | 100 | 95 |
| 4 | 100 | 90 |

HOW will be the SQL query?

Comment: you are sorting when you get the result and every row has an id.

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean exactly

Comment: I only need the specific position like as 2nd row this, 6th row this, 100th row this etc.

Comment: Additionally,  I have some students marks, I want to know only which place one of the students acquires.

Comment: If there are ties, how do you want to count rank?  E.g. if you have marks 40,40,60,60 are their ranks 1,1,2,2? 1,1,3,3? 1,2,3,4?  What mysql version?

Comment: If ties, I will look at data inserting time by a other column.  MySQL version 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK`/`ROW_NUMBER()` as follows:

```
select student_id, exam_id, marks,
       dense_rank() over (partition by exam_id order by marks desc) as exact_position
  from students
order by exam_id, exact_position
```